# Keyset does not exist when accessing certificate from azure web site

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate

When I access a certificate from the file system, either locally, or on an azure website, with the following code, I have no problems:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(
    keyFilePath,
    "mysecret",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet
    | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet
    | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

However, when I follow the instructions at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/ for utilizing the azure certificate store, everything works for the first 3 to 9 requests, and all subsequent calls fail on the following line

```
var rsa = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
```

with the error "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist" until the site is restarted, and will then work for another at least 3 requests.

I'm baffled as to why it works for at least 3 and up to 9 requests, then always fails with the error. I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 5):

When loading from the PFX you were specifying PersistKeySet, which should usually only be set when you are planning on persisting the certificate to a cert store. Though it's possible that some aspect of the code tried being clever and cleaning up the private key on it's own, by marking an RSACryptoServiceProvider object's `PersistKeyInCsp` to `false`.

The reason I point this out is that the "Keyset does not exist" error almost always means "the cert store was told that a private key existed, but someone has since deleted it without informing the cert store".  The most likely culprit is something somewhere setting `PersistKeyInCsp` to `false` (which means "delete the key file on Dispose/Finalize").

If you are setting PersistKeyInCsp to false but not disposing the object manually, you'd get a deferred cleanup due to the finalizer, which would explain why it's 3-9 successes instead of a deterministic number.

(I also feel compelled to point out that you should use `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()` instead of `cert.PrivateKey`, because a) it's type-safe and b) it's caller-owned lifetime (you're supposed to dispose it) instead of shared/ambiguous lifetime.  It makes things a bit more predictable, though it almost never returns an RSACryptoServiceProvider, so you shouldn't try to cast it)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to "fix" the issue by not setting PersistKeyInCsp to false. Unfortunately x509Certificates and Cryptography are well outside my wheelhouse; the code I am working with is a library we found online to generate tokens for Google firebase. While I'm now unblocked, clearly I should so some reasearch as to the inner workings of this, and not treat that library as a black box.

Comment: I changed `new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)` to `new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)`  (ie: I removed PersistKeySet) but it doesnt work. It throws "Keyset does not exist" randomly...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like explicit disposal (with `using` keyword) solves the problem:

```
using (X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "mysecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                   X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
                   X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable))
{
// ... use cert
}
```

Comment: I finished up with using BouncyCastle. This (with X509...) solution worked locally and in Azure Web App, but not in Functions, where only BouncyCastle helped.

Comment: Can confirm that BouncyCastly seems to be the only reliable solution. Had issues without it in the past, mostly when under heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton worked for me:

```
  class static CertificateSingleton
  {
       private static X509Certificate2 certificate;

       public Get()
       {
            if (certificate == null) 
            {
                 byte[] certificateBytes = .....;
                 string password = .....;

                 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            }

            return certificate;
       }
  }
```

So everytime I want to use it, I use `CertificatesSingleton.Get()` and this guarantees I'm using the same instance everytime.